# EWS Exception: There are no public folder servers available

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, public-folders

I am trying to get Public folders email from my outlook mailbox. Presently, I can get the mails from the folders in my root folder. I use the following code for the same:

```
      Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(exchange, WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot);

      //Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(exchange, WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot); // gives error                 


      rootfolder.Load();
      foreach (Folder folder in rootfolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)))
       {
           Console.WriteLine(folder.DisplayName);
       }
```

When I replace `WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot` with `WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot`, I get the error "There are no public folder servers available." I also referred to @Mimi Gentz solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911206/how-to-get-public-folders-from-one-public-folder-mailbox-in-exchange-2013-via-ew), but I still get the error.

Am I missing something in my code ? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My email is on Office365 whereas public folders are OnPrem, which is why I get `no public folder servers` error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start by adding in the correct routing headers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-route-public-folder-hierarchy-requests . The other thing is that by default there won't be public folders OnPrem or Office365 so an administrator would have to have setup them up first.

Comment: But I can see the Public Folders in my mailbox. It should means that either Public Folders should be OnPrem or Office365.

Comment: The public folders are set for OnPrem.

Comment: Will I be able to access the public folders through EWS, if mailbox is on Office365 whereas public folders are OnPrem? I am guessing, I won't be able to do so, which is why I am getting the error.